# installing pyfftw thrown error missing fftw header file

Tags: python, pip, fftw, pyfftw

I am trying to install pyfftw on windows 32 bits. I had to install fftw. So 
 
 1.I downloaded fftw-3.3.5-dll32.zip from here http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

2.I unzipped files and by developer command prompet for vs2019 I ran this commands : 
lib /machine:x86 /def:libfftw3-3.def 
lib /machine:x86 /def:libfftw3f-3.def
lib /machine:x86 /def:libfftw3l-3.def

3.I add folder path to variable path


4.pip install pyfftw thrown an error : could not find the fftw header 'fftw3.h'


Does anybody know the solution?

Tnx for your help

Comment: Same here. I tried both `pip install pyfftw` and `pip install pyFFTW`. Could be broken?..

Comment: No I don't think so. I tried pip install pyfftw on 64 bits, and it worked. I think, I missed something? Did you try to install fftw?

Comment: If you mean the c package no

Comment: To be clear, where did you get pyfftw from? Might it be the same problem [described here](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/289), then posed [here](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/290)? (specifically, trying to use pyfftw3 not pyfftw, two different projects).